# Exchangelib close connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, exchangelib

I want to know if there's a way to close the connection with [exchangelib](https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/).

Here is my function for setup and connection; I need to define a `close_conection()` function, but haven't found anything reading the documentation.

```
class Exchange:
    def __init__(self, username, password, server):
        """"""
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.server = server  
    def account(self):
        """Setup and connecting"""
        creds = Credentials(
            username=self.username,
            password=self.password
        )
        config = Configuration(server=self.server, credentials=creds)
        account = Account(
            primary_smtp_address=self.username,
            autodiscover=False, 
            config=config,
            access_type=DELEGATE
        )
        return account
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exchangelib will close TCP connections on garbage collection. See https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/3c10bc7ad0e0ba2aa0b4a55eb95d234ff8c6091a/exchangelib/protocol.py#L114

You can also close connections explicitly with: `account.protocol.close()`

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer in such a short time, it helped me a lot!

Comment: @Ralf Thanks for trying to help, but your text edit isn’t what I needed...